# Ruby module function in Rails View, manually rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails view for XLSX that's called by `ApplicationController.render`.

```rb
# app/views/my_spreadsheet.xlsx.axlsx - I want to do this... can't.

money_addition_func(...)


# models/concerns/money_functions.rb

module MoneyFunctions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def money_addition_func(...)
end
```

I would like to do above, where I can use `money_addition_func`. Normally I would `include` it in the controller and reference it via `helper_method` but since it's going through a background job via render function, I don't have that.

I could make it `self.money_addition_func` allowing me to perform `MoneyFunctions.money_addition_func` but this feels overkill plus requires me to change a bunch of references all over the place.

Is there anyway to include a module in a view that is manually rendered? (i.e. not through a controller?)

Comment: `include MoneyFunctions` - its really that simple. Depending on how you're rendering you can include it in view context instead of doing it in the view itself.

Comment: @max Ah you're right! How could I forget about `self.class_eval`. If you want to answer, I'll accept.